# Unable to locate persister for the entity, no code has changed

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am suddenly getting the error: "Unable to locate persister for the entity named 'MyLib.Project'."

I did not make any code changes to this project since the last time I published it. The reason I went into the code to look at it is because a user reported that the web page that utilizes this library was giving an error. I have also checked the eager loading of the provider as per  ([NHibernate - Random occurrences of "Unable to locate persister"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099018/nhibernate-random-occurrences-of-unable-to-locate-persister)) but I am already eagerly loading.

Furthermore, I even changed my data provider configuration to:

```
.Mappings(Function(x) x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf(Of Project)())
```

I stepped through the code and actually saw it find the Project mapping and step through it. There are no exceptions thrown while building the provider, but yet the web app still fails when I try to fetch a Project from the DB.

**Update**
I have tested this same exact code with a desktop application and it works perfectly fine. It seems to me the problem must be with NHibernate and the Web Application. Does anyone have any ideas about this specifically?

Comment: Close the solution and re-open it - it is still in error?

Comment: Yes, this problem still persists even after re-opening the solution.

Comment: log the inner exception, wherever this error occurs. The inner exception usually should tell you what the reason is

Comment: The inner exception is `Nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this, of course, is that I made a mistake.

I had two session factories in use in the same program and I passed a session from the wrong factory to one of my functions. So the error is correct, because the session it was passed was unaware of the `Project` type. I found this out eventually by looking at the `Connection` property of the session I was querying through.

Hopefully this helps someone else who may have made the same mistake.